# Number Switch Statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement

So I am trying to make this simple program, but using the switch statement when I run the program no matter what I put in, I always get the default answer. How can I make it to where it will choose the correct statement for the number I put in?

```
int number;

Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 0 and 50: ");
number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

switch (number )
{
     case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("Do you not know how to count? That's more than 50!");
        break;
     case 2:
         Console.WriteLine("Did I say you could choose a number below 0?");                 
         break;
     default:
         Console.WriteLine("Good job smarty pants!");
         break;
}        
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You should try debugging and see the path it's actually taking through your code, observe the value of your `number`, etc.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You are telling the user to enter a number between 0 and 50, but you're switch statement only compares it against `1` and `2`.

Comment: You have not clearly stated what you are trying to accomplish. What is the expected output.  Don't make us guess based on the code.

Comment: You will always get the default message unless you type 1 or 2

Comment: I don't think you understand switch statements. You switch on the variable `number`, which is user input. When you say case 1:, that means this case executes if the user input is 1.

Answer (score 6):

Eh, just `if` and `else if`:

```
  if (number > 50)
    Console.WriteLine("Do you not know how to count? That's more than 50!");
  else if (number < 0) 
    Console.WriteLine("Did I say you could choose a number below 0?");           
  else
    Console.WriteLine("Good job smarty pants!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in this case you are trying to fit a tool to a use it was not designed for. The case is really for distinct cases over a solution space, not continuous ones. (The difference between the answer can be -1 or 1 and the answer can be < 0 and > 0). That being said, I support user Dmitry Bychenko's answer which states to use an `if` and `else if` to accomplish this task. I am sure you could devise a way to use a `switch` statement but it would be like using a hammer's back side to sand a floor.

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening in your code is that the `number` you have read is unlikely to ever be 1 or 2 which is what will be compared. What you have currently converted to an `if...else` (which is easier to outline the problem with) would be:

```
if (number == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do you not know how to count? That's more than 50!");
}
else if (number == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Did I say you could choose a number below 0?");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Good job smarty pants!");
}
```

That should help you see what your actual issue is, although I will point it out that it appears you want to limit the user to a value between 0...50 but you are actually only checking that the number entered is equal to 1 or 2. You could use a switch statement for this type of problem but as you will still need to make sure the number is valid an `if...else` is slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You also can try this:

```
int number = 12;
Dictionary<Func<int, bool>, Action> dict = new Dictionary<Func<int, bool>, Action>
            {
                {x => x < 0, () => Console.WriteLine("Smaller than 0")},
                {x => x > 50, () => Console.WriteLine("Greater than 50")},
                {x => (x >= 0 && x <= 50), () => Console.WriteLine("Between 0 and 50")}
            };

dict.First(kvp => kvp.Key(number)).Value();
```